# How do I schedule the execution of a python script in linux with the at command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks

My goal is to schedule the execution of a simple python script in Linux with the `at` command.

Problem: My python script is not executed at the specified time. Nothing happens, no error messages.

I have the following simple `helloworld` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

print("hello world")
```

To schedule the job I type:

```
at now + 1 min
```

I provide the file I want to execute:

```
./helloworld
```

Typing `atq` I see that the job was scheduled nicely.

But it just happens...nothing.

- I work on Kali Linux
- I have given execution permission to the root user for that file
- I can run the `helloworld` file from the command line
- the root user has permission to run at commands (not listed in `/etc/at.deny`)
- I can schedule the job `echo "hello world" > message.txt`. That works fine.

What I am not sure about:

- is there something wrong with the shebang line?
- I have checked `/usr/bin/`: `python3` is in there and is linked to `python3.9`.

Comment: What is your indication that the program does not, in fact, run? Output from at jobs has traditionally been e-mailed to the owner of the job, but on present-day Linux installations, that mechanism tends to be broken out-of-the-box (though I'm not familiar with Kali).

Comment: Is `atd` daemon running?

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, atd is running

Comment: @TurePålsson ok, you may be right...I expected that the output of my executed python file will be printed to the screen. Am I wrong? I can run the python shell script from the command line and the output is printed to the screen. I assumend I can also schedule the execution of the same shell script? How can I check if the at command worked after you?

Comment: As I said, traditionally, output from at jobs has been mailed, as there is no guarantee that the user is still logged in when the job runs. Just as you tried with `echo hello >file.txt`, you could do `./helloworld >file.txt` and see whether file.txt gets created.

Comment: @TurePålsson Good point, man. Finally, someone could help me...you are right. Then the big misunderstanding that I had was, that the output is not going to be printed to the my shell because this isn't a python shell! :-) Thanks, now it's clear...

Comment: @TurePålsson ...well, I tell the system to use the python interpreter, so far so good. But, to be honest, I still don't understand exactly why the output cannot be printed into the shell. I mean, when I can run the file from the command line, why can it not be run as a scheduled job?? This remains a secret for me...anyway, it is as it is...;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`at` does not write to the terminal (which may not even exist when the command runs). Instead,

> The user will be mailed standard error and standard output from his commands, if any.  Mail will be sent using the command sendmail(8).  If at is executed from a su(1) shell, the owner of the login shell will receive the mail.

So if your command only writes to standard output, you'll need to check the local mailbox for the output of the command, using `mail` or some other mail client.

Otherwise, you can have your command explicitly write to some other known file to look for later.

Answer (score 0):

0. It is better to keep the extension `.py` for your script since it is python.
1. Your file should be executable

```sh
$ chmod +x ./helloworld
```

2. For your needs, you can just type the full path to your script when running `at`.
3. If you want to use `helloworld` command, the folder that contains this script should be in `PATH` environment variable. Otherwise, the system just doesn't know where to find it. If you do this, you don't need to type `./` before the command or any path at all.
   Nice article about `PATH` https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux

Comment: Thanks, Sergei Malanin. Nice article indeed and exactly what I am learning about these days. But let us clarify this: I don't need to add my file path to the PATH variable if I precisely indicate the file path...am I wrong. Only if I want the system to look for the file itself, then I have to add it to the PATH variable...in my example, I tell the system exactly where to look for the file.

Comment: This is dubious or incorrect on several counts. There is no particular reason to favor a `.py` extension for Python scripts; it is perfectly okay to leave off in some situations, just like `which` isn't named `which.pl` and `ls` isn't `ls.bin`. The command `./helloworld` will only look in the current directory and completely ignore the `PATH`.